# Como criar um botão para cada item de uma ListView que acesse uma música

Tags: android, listview

Queria que cada item da `ListView` tocasse uma música ao clicar o botão referente a cada item, porém, quando eu clico no botão, ele até toca, só q somente a primeira música, as demais músicas da lista não tocam.

Eu usei um `listview` personalizado na atividade principal e meu `adapter` está assim:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Itens>{

private MediaPlayer mMedia; 

(...)

final Button playButton = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.start);

if (item.hasAudio()){
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
públic void onClick (View v){
mMedia = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),item.getAudio());
mMedia.start();
mMedia.onCompletionListener = (...)}

return Layout;}
```

Comment: já fez algum código, qual linguagem está utilizando?

Comment: O que você já tem? Essa sua dúvida envolve muitas etapas e uma resposta completa seria inviável. Concentre-se num problema específico.

Comment: Arrumei a pergunta. Vc sabe como consertar? A linguagem é android.

Answer (score 1):

No Evento SelectedIndexChanged você pode tocar a música fazendo o seguinte.

**Instale o pacote NAudio**  (Package Manager Console) - Nuget

> Install-Package NAudio

Se você quiser que uma música toque a mudança de item no seu List:

```
private void lstItens_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IWavePlayer waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
    AudioFileReader audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(@"C:\temp\songs\song1.mp3");

    waveOutDevice.Init(audioFileReader);
    waveOutDevice.Play();
}
```

Sendo assim você pode incrementar seu código para cada item você selecionar um arquivo de som.. e por aí vai.

Não esqueça de quando voce for dar um Stop:

```
waveOutDevice.Stop();
audioFileReader.Dispose();
waveOutDevice.Dispose();
```